# JOLT Nested if condition

Tags: jolt

I have this input JSON:

```json
{
  "user": "123456",
  "product": "television",
  "category": "electronics",
  "tag": "summer"
}
```

And this transformation:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "product": {
        "@(1,product)": "item",
        "@(1,user)": {
          "#2": "userBias"
        }
      },
      "user": {
        "@(1,user)": "user"
      },
      "category": {
        "#category": "rules.[0].name",
        "@(1,category)": "rules.[0].values[0]"
      },
      "tag": {
        "rules": "rules",
        "#tag": "rules.[1].name",
        "@(2,tag)": "rules.[1].values[0]"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "userBias?": "=toInteger"
    }
  }
]
```

Which works fine and produces the following JSON:

```json
{
  "item": "television",
  "userBias": 2,
  "user": "123456",
  "rules": [
    {
      "name": "category",
      "values": [
        "electronics"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "tag",
      "values": [
        "summer"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

If from the input though I delete `"category": "electronics"` so it becomes:

```json
{
  "user": "123456",
  "product": "television",
  "tag": "summer"
}
```

Then i get back the following result:

```json
{
  "item": "television",
  "userBias": 2,
  "user": "123456",
  "rules": [
    null,
    {
      "name": "tag",
      "values": [
        "summer"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The problem with the above is that it contains a null element inside the array and I do not know how to get rid of it. I have tried with **recursivelySquashNulls** but it does not work.
Also basically what am looking for is if both category and tag exist then tag should go to rules[1] if only tag exists then tag should go to rules[0].

Thanks in advance,
giannis

Answer (score 0):

Because you specify `tag` and `category` elements individually. Rather, prefer putting them into the category rest by combining them under asterisked key notation such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "product": {
        "@(1,product)": "item",
        "@(1,user)": {
          "#2": "userBias"
        }
      },
      "user": {
        "@(1,user)": "user"
      },
      "*": {
        "$": "r[0].&.name",
        "@(1,&)": "r[0].&.values[]"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "r": {
        "*": { "*": "rules" }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "userBias?": "=toInteger"
    }
  }
]
```

***Result1*** :
[image]

***Result2***(without `"category": "electronics"` pair for the Input) :
[image]